# Google Webmaster Data-Highlighter shows adult links in site. None found in source code

Tags: google-search-console, links, spam

Google Webmaster Data-Highlighter shows that adult links in site but on checking the source code in browser links are not shown.

[image: Google Data Highlighter screenshots]

Even the sucuri is showing site is clean.  https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/repairmymobile.in

Plz help... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source code of the page as its cached in Google, you will see the links:

[image]

You won't see them when just viewing the source code as some one has hacked your site, injected the links and set them so they only display when Google-bot is crawling the site.

They do this to build back links which can help the SEO of the sites they are linking to. This is known an Black Hat SEO.

It doesn't sound like you have the experience to clean the site yourself, so you should probably consultant a professional. If you Google for something such as 'hack repair' you will find someone who can help you remove the hack from your site.

Comment: Can you suggest some source to fix it.

Comment: Fix the code. You're most likely running out dated scripts or nulled template script.

Comment: There are computer viruses that effect various CMS/Blog software that leave no trace within the CMS/Blog code/database. Update all your code immediately. Run an antivirus including rootkit against the entire hard drive to be sure. For Linux, you can use CLAM. For Windows, the options are vast.